# Spam users to dispose of

Tags: support, spam, spammer

> "http://www.top-password.com/reset-windows-password.html" site:serverfault.com

That search gave me a nice list of posts that got missed when we started spam-flagging. There are three users used for linking to that site:

https://serverfault.com/users/43855/user43855
https://serverfault.com/users/43854/user43854
https://serverfault.com/users/44036/justtimgreen

All posts are on password recovery type questions, and all link to the same site.

Comment: You didn't tag this as "dirty-spamming-spammer-spam"?

Comment: @andrew I was really tempted by, "Some bloody Vikings need to get ejected."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding these:

https://serverfault.com/users/48779/robfluth
https://serverfault.com/users/49480/user49480
https://serverfault.com/users/51395/rcmz
https://serverfault.com/users/43858/user43858
https://serverfault.com/users/49483/user49483
https://serverfault.com/users/43857/user43857
https://serverfault.com/users/48676/password-recovery
https://serverfault.com/users/52000/deminemo[image: NEW]

Same deal. Password reset questions

Comment: All gone.......

Answer (score 6):

Instead of posting these on here (I can't look everywhere) could you just mod-alert them please - it's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

And I will add this one. I am shocked somebody bothered with stock-spam on a site like serverfault...

https://serverfault.com/users/59401/arleen-walker